# Is every LL(1) grammar also a LALR(1) grammar?

Tags: parsing, compiler-construction

So one source says it is and another says its not

one source says this :

[image: https://qph.fs.quoracdn.net/main-qimg-a94c48361571eeafdd5ba5fb63c24729-c]

another says this :

[image]

the closest answer i found is this :

[Relationship between LR(0), LL(0), LALR(1), etc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36652221/relationship-between-lr0-ll0-lalr1-etc)

but this doesn't answer the relation between LL(1) and LALR(1)

**also** if you can answer the more general question, which is what is the relation between LL(k) and LALR(k) it would be even more helpful

thanks.

Comment: I don't know where the first chart comes from, but it's totally unreliable. Operator precedence *grammars* are LR(1). There are people (and Wikipedia) who seem to think that the word "precedence" is not relevant, but that's untrue. **Operator** grammars may be ambiguous and thus not LR(1), but if a precedence relationship can be derived, the grammar is LR(1).

Comment: @rici  how can Operator precedence grammars be LR(1) when Operator precedence grammars   can be  ambiguous  ?  does that mean if a grammar is Operator precedence then i can 100% be sure that it is LR(1) as well  ? also do you have a source for that? thanks

Comment: an operator grammar is operator precedence if there is at most one precedence relation for any point in a parse. A `<•` relation is a shift action and `•>` is a reduce.  So there can be no shift-reduce conflicts. Proving the absence of reduce-reduce conflicts is only slightly more complicated.

Comment: arbitrary operator grammars can be ambiguous and you could build an operator precedence parser not based on the grammar's precedence relations. That doesn't make the grammar operator-precedence, though (imho). That's the issue with the Wikipedia page, for example.

Comment: And if you want sources, ask on an academic site like [cs.se]. Here we're pragmatic programmers.

Comment: @rici alright thanks man

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The definitive answer (at least on the SE Network) can be found in this  [answer](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/43/4416) in the [computing science](https://cs.stackexchange.com/) site, where parsing theory questions are likely to attract better responses.

When reading the charts in that answer, note that there is a difference between containment relationships for *grammars* and containment relationships for *languages*. One of the clearest instances of this is the fact that all LR(k) grammars can be mechanically transformed into LR(1) grammars, with the consequence that there are only two categories of LR *languages*: LR(0) and LR(1). (In fact, you can reduce LR(k) languages to SLR(1), so the various algorithmic distinctions also disappear at the language level.) LL(k) languages, on the other hand, are a strict containment hierarchy. And the union of LL(k) languages (for finite k) is a strict subset of LR(1).

For grammars, though, the relationships are not so simple. Clearly, LL(k), LR(k), LALR(k), SLR(k), etc., form hierarchies, intuitively because it is not necessary to use all the lookahead information, and because for any grammar it is possible to add productions which require k+1 lookaheads (for both LL and LR algorithms).

LL(k) grammars are necessarily LR(k) but they are not necessarily LALR(k). There is an exercise in [Appel's Modern Compiler Implementation textbook](https://www.cs.princeton.edu/~appel/modern/) which provides an example of an LL(1) grammar which is not LALR(1); you can find the grammar transcribed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6492798/1566221). That should provide an idea on how to construct examples for k > 1. (Finding LALR(k) grammars which are not LL(k) is trivial: all you need is left recursion.)